# I am trying to access data in a C# packet I've created, however I keep getting null as a response. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c#, networking, packet

Okay, so I'm working with custom network code for pretty much the first time. I have a packet created to transfer some game information back and forth, however beyond the initial content if I try to access some of the commands, I get "null" - though on the server side, it's showing as properly populated.

I have a feeling that this has to do with the setup in receiving the data. The code for the packet follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;


public enum DataIdentifier
{
    Message,
    Command,
    LogIn,
    LogOut,
    Null
}

public class Packet
{
    private DataIdentifier dataIdentifier;

    private string name;
    private string player;
    private string playerData;
    private string message;

    private string command;
    private string x;
    private string y;
    private string z;


    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }

        set
        {
            name = value;
        }
    }

    public string Player
    {
        get
        {
            return player;
        }

        set
        {
            player = value;
        }
    }

    public string Message
    {
        get
        {
            return message;
        }

        set
        {
            message = value;
        }
    }

    public string Command
    {
        get
        {
            return command;
        }

        set
        {
            command = value;
        }
    }

    public DataIdentifier DataIdentifier
    {
        get
        {
            return dataIdentifier;
        }

        set
        {
            dataIdentifier = value;
        }
    }

    public string PlayerData
    {
        get
        {
            return playerData;
        }

        set
        {
            playerData = value;
        }
    }

    public string X
    {
        get
        {
            return x;
        }

        set
        {
            x = value;
        }
    }

    public string Y
    {
        get
        {
            return y;
        }

        set
        {
            y = value;
        }
    }

    public string Z
    {
        get
        {
            return z;
        }

        set
        {
            z = value;
        }
    }

    public Packet()
    {
        this.DataIdentifier = DataIdentifier.Null;
        this.message = null;
        this.name = null;
        this.player = null;
        this.playerData = null;
        this.x = null;
        this.y = null;
        this.z = null;
        this.command = null;
    }

    public Packet(byte[] dataStream)
    {
        // Read the data identifier from the beginning of the stream (4 bytes)
        this.DataIdentifier = (DataIdentifier)BitConverter.ToInt32(dataStream, 0);

        // Read the length of the name (4 bytes)
        int nameLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(dataStream, 4);

        // Read the length of the message (4 bytes)
        int msgLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(dataStream, 8);



        // Read the name field
        if (nameLength > 0)
            this.name = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(dataStream, 12, nameLength);
        else
            this.name = null;

        // Read the message field
        if (msgLength > 0)
            this.message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(dataStream, 12 + nameLength, msgLength);
        else
            this.message = null;


    }

    public byte[] GetDataStream()
    {
        List<byte> dataStream = new List<byte>();

        // Add the dataIdentifier
        dataStream.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes((int)this.DataIdentifier));

        // Add the name length
        if (this.name != null)
            dataStream.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(this.name.Length));
        else
            dataStream.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(0));

        // Add the message length
        if (this.message != null)
            dataStream.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(this.message.Length));
        else
            dataStream.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(0));

        // Add the name
        if (this.name != null)
            dataStream.AddRange(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(this.name));

        // Add the message
        if (this.message != null)
            dataStream.AddRange(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(this.message));

        if (this.playerData != null)
        {
            dataStream.AddRange(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(this.playerData));
        }

        if (this.command != null)
        {
            dataStream.AddRange(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(this.command));
        }

        if (this.x != null)
        {
            dataStream.AddRange(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(this.x));
        }

        if (this.y != null)
        {
            dataStream.AddRange(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(this.y));
        }

        if (this.z != null)
        {
            dataStream.AddRange(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(this.z));
        }

        return dataStream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

This is how the packet is recieved:

```
                // Receive all data
            this.clientSocket.EndReceive(AR);
            // Initialise a packet object to store the received data
            Packet receivedData = new Packet(this.dataStream);
            // Evaulate command played 
            if (PacketDelegate != null)
            {
                PacketDelegate(receivedData);
            }
            // Reset data stream
            this.dataStream = new byte[8142];
            // Continue listening for broadcasts
            clientSocket.BeginReceiveFrom(this.dataStream, 0, this.dataStream.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref epServer, new AsyncCallback(this.ReceiveCallback), null);
```

And this is the delegate function responsible for handling a packet:

```
public void RecievePacket(Packet Communication)
{
    // Check and manipulate the contents of the packet here //
}
```

I have confirmed that I can get name, DataIdentifier, and Message, but it's the additional information I've added to the packet itself - player/data, command, x,y,z, I can't seem to get.

My thought is that the problem exists in establishing Packet(byte[] dataStream). However, I'm not quite sure how to calculate or add the additional variables to this. Can anyone give me some tips on how to do so?

Comment: Is your received dataStream equal to the one you send? Can you check that?

Comment: how are you transferring the data?

Comment: UDP socket connection. I've added a bit more to the code to show how I receive data and process it.

Comment: Your de/serialization code is buggy, you encode the length of the string instead of the number of bytes in the utf8 encoded value of the string.  Always best to not reinvent this, consider xml serialization or a library like protobuf.